# Como fazer com que '$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']' aceite variáveis GET

Tags: php, get

Olá, tenho a seguinte condição:

```
  if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] != '/painel/cardapio.php'){
        header('Location: cardapio.php');
      }
```

porém estou tendo problema porque o `cardapio.php` pode ser acessado através de GET como `cardapio.php?etapa=2`

Como faço para que minha condição aceite o acesso de cardapio.php com variáveis GET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Graças a ajuda do Miguel consegui resolver o problema usando a seguinte solução

```
$isCardapio= strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/painel/cardapio.php');
if($isCardapio=== false){
  header('Location: cardapio.php');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Pode fazer com [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php), pode ser usada para ver se uma string contem algum conjunto de chars:

```
if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/painel/cardapio.php') === False) { // caso não contenha vamos redirecionar
    header('Location: cardapio.php');
}
```

Ou pode ir pelo nome do ficheiro:

```
if(basename(__FILE__) != 'cardapio.php') {
    header('Location: cardapio.php');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Acho que poderia utilizar o $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']

```
if ($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']!= '/painel/cardapio.php') {
      header('Location: cardapio.php')
}
```